# XSD schema: using multiple xmime with expectedContentTypes

Tags: xsd, schema

I've a XSD \ schema with an element (as shown below). This element is expected to have either CSV or XML data. I am not sure what expectedContentTypes to use. I can think of the following but not sure:

> text/*
>
> */*

```
<xs:element name="Data" type="xs:base64Binary" xmime:expectedContentTypes="text/*"/>
```

or is there any other way? like

> "text/csv;text/xml"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, your element Data type should be derived from xmime:base64Binary. `text/*` is correct, or `text/csv,text/xml` - a comma should be used instead.

However, why binary encoding when you're shipping text? One thing to consider is the size of the message, with base64 encoding your result will register about 30% overhead.

Have you considered this XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--W3C Schema generated by QTAssistant/W3C Schema Refactoring Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="Data">
        <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Any XML below will work equally; XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
     <something></something>
</Data>
```

CSV:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
    A,B,B
    1,2,3
</Data>
```

In other words, you could have the XML, the CSV, or both. If you don't want both, there are tricks to ensure stronger data typing.